Problem: Unable to Locate <input> Field After Clicking Login Button in Playwright
Please help me.
I am trying to create a Python script to log in to icloud.com. I can't find the element responsible for the email field.
How can I ensure that the input field is found after clicking the login button?
Are there specific techniques for handling dynamic content or iframe elements in Playwright that I might be missing?
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

input_selector = "input#account_name_text_field"

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()

    page.goto("https://www.icloud.com/")
    page.wait_for_load_state("load")
    print("Page loaded")

    try:
        page.click(".sign-in-button")
        print("Login button clicked")

        page.wait_for_timeout(5000)  # Wait 5 seconds after clicking the login button
        print("Waited 5 seconds after clicking the login button.")

        # Check if the page contains iframes
        iframes = page.query_selector_all("iframe")
        print(f"Found {len(iframes)} iframe(s) on the page.")

        if len(iframes) > 0:
            for i, iframe in enumerate(iframes):
                print(f"Checking iframe {i + 1}")
                iframe_page = iframe.content_frame()
                input_field = iframe_page.query_selector(input_selector)

                if input_field:
                    print(f"Found input field in iframe {i + 1}.")
                    input_field.fill("diminkl@icloud.com")
                    print("Filled the email field in the iframe.")
                    break
            else:
                print("Did not find input field in any iframe.")
        else:
            print("No iframes found on the page.")
            input_field = page.query_selector(input_selector)
            if input_field:
                input_field.fill("1234@icloud.com")
                print("Filled the email field on the page.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

    browser.close()```


You should use locators instead of query_selector
